# mapStateToProps state param has an unexpected field '0'.like { 0 : { searchResults : [] } }

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to this.
There are two different states from `mapStateToProps` and `reducer`

mapStateToProps function log an object like `{ 0 : { searchResults : [] } }`

I want to know why the object has `0` and how to remove it

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        searchResults:state.searchResults
    }
}
```

reducer function return an object like `{ searchResults : [] }`

```
export function reducer(state = {},action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case ACTION_SEARCHRESULT:
            return Object.assign({},state,{
                searchResults:[]
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

how can I change this code? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Please give your post a better title to describe the problem at hand.

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally using an array somewhere?

Comment: You have to provide more code

Comment: The snippets you provided look fine

Comment: thanks,i think maybe not.There is only one mapStateToProps function and one reducer function in this code @AndrewLi

Comment: Sorry,I'm not at home. so i can't provide more code.And I think other code dose not use the state param or this.state or getState...So I don't know how to do @CodinCat

Comment: Do you use combineReducers? What's your code of createStore? You may need to provide all other code